# Is there a delete queue?

Tags: support

Right now I occasionally stumble upon a (closed) question that needs to be deleted (e.g. an ID question or a recommendation question), but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to find them. Considering that such questions often receive multiple down-votes and thus disappear off the front page, they're almost impossible to find very soon.

Sure, they'll be deleted in due time by the "hoover", but wouldn't it be better to speed up this process?

Is there a queue where one can see the questions that are "nominated" to be deleted? If not, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the moderator tools section, found under movies.stackexchange.com/tools or in the tools tab on the review page, you can see (among others) a list of posts that have gained recent delete votes. You could see this as a very basic queue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aha: https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete . Thank you very much!